# acts_as_tree not working with sinatra

Tags: sinatra, acts-as-tree, sinatra-activerecord

I cant get acts_as_tree working with sinatra. 
I keep getting the following error.

```
undefined method `acts_as_tree' for User
```

I think its not supported for Sinatra.
Any input is welcome.
Just additional information.
I am using Sinatra ActiveRecord

Comment: can you show how you've required Sinatra ActiveRecord and acts_as_tree?

Comment: @iain both have been added in the Gemfile. Also i have included ActsAsTree in my user.rb

Comment: Ok. Have you called `Bundler.setup`? Have you added `require 'acts_as_tree` in `user.rb`?

Comment: Yes i ran bundle and also added require 'acts_as_tree' to my user.rb

Comment: You did this? http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html

Comment: Did you put in your app file `require "acts_as_tree"` and `require "activerecord"`?